# How to get result from a luaSQL query?

Tags: mysql, lua

So I'm trying to do a count query within a command from lua SQL, using a mySQL database. I want to get the current count of users within a table, however I'm quite lost with using lua as a language and incorporating a database to it.

So far, this is what I have:

```
exec,err = connect:execute("SELECT count(user_id) AS count FROM Users")
    testString = string.format("%d", exec:numrows())
    if exec:numrows() == 0 then
        send_msg(receiver, teststring, ok_cb, false)
    end
```

I've checked it with another script and it's value that it returns is 1, however I want to get the value within the row... How would I go about doing this with luaSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Okay instead of making this harder on myself, I just decided to remove the count command from the SQL statement, and use the numrows statement within luaSQL, kind of like this:

```
exec,err = connect:execute("SELECT user_id FROM Users")
if exec:numrows() == 0 then
    send_msg(receiver, "test", ok_cb, false)
end
```